# How to call a variable created in the script in Nextflow?

Tags: bash, bioinformatics, nextflow

I have a nextflow script that creates a variable from a text file, and I need to pass the value of that variable to a command line order (which is a bioconda package). Those two processes happen inside the "script" part. I have tried to call the variable using the '$' symbol without any results, I think because using that symbol in the script part of a nextflow script is for calling variables defined in the input part.

To make myself clearer, here is a code sample of what I'm trying to achieve:

```
params.gz_file = '/path/to/file.gz'
params.fa_file = '/path/to/file.fa'
params.output_dir = '/path/to/outdir'

input_file = file(params.gz_file)
fasta_file = file(params.fa_file)

process foo {
    //publishDir "${params.output_dir}", mode: 'copy',

    input:
    path file from input_file
    path fasta from fasta_file

    output:
    file ("*.html")

    script:
    """
    echo 123 > number.txt
    parameter=`cat number.txt`
    create_report $file $fasta --flanking $parameter 
    """
}
```

By doig this the error I recieve is:

```
Error executing process > 'foo'
Caused by:
  Unknown variable 'parameter' -- Make sure it is not misspelt and defined somewhere in the script before using it
```

Is there any way to call the variable `parameter` inside the script without Nextflow interpreting it as an input file? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The documentation re the [script block](https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/process.html#script) is useful here:

> Since Nextflow uses the same Bash syntax for variable substitutions in
> strings, you need to manage them carefully depending on if you want to
> evaluate a variable in the Nextflow context - or - in the Bash
> environment execution.

One solution is to escape your shell (Bash) variables by prefixing them with a back-slash (`\`) character, like in the following example:

```
process foo {

    script:
    """
    echo 123 > number.txt
    parameter="\$(cat number.txt)"
    echo "\${parameter}"
    """
}
```

Another solution is to instead use a [shell block](https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/process.html#shell), where dollar (`$`) variables are managed by your shell (Bash interpreter), while exclamation mark (`!`) variables are handled by Nextflow. For example:

```
process bar {

    echo true

    input:
    val greeting from 'Hello', 'Hola', 'Bonjour'

    shell:
    '''
    echo 123 > number.txt
    parameter="$(cat number.txt)"
    echo "!{greeting} parameter ${parameter}"
    '''
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this detailed answer! It worked perfectly, both of the options :)

Comment: how would I have to edit / add the output to forward the value of parameter into a value channel?

Comment: @tristan https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70274226/how-to-call-a-forward-the-value-of-a-variable-created-in-the-script-in-nextflow

Answer (score -2):

declare "parameter" in the top 'params' section.

```
params.parameter="1234"
(..)
script:
"""
(...)
create_report $file $fasta --flanking ${params.parameter} 
(...)
"""
(...)
```

and call "nextflow run" with "--parameter 87678"

Comment: A workflow parameter won't help if the value that's required needs to be computed on the fly like in the example.